# How to insert a reference field type using Firestore Python SDK?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore document and want to add a field to this document of type `reference`. It is a reference to another document in another collection.

Example:
We have two collections named `messages` and `users`. Within the collection `messages` we have a document with the doc-ID `msgId1`. Now we want to add a field of type reference with this doc-ID to a user document within the `users` collection.

```js
user
{
  firstName: 'tessty',
  lastName: 'Toast',
  msg: msgId1
}
```

At the moment I use [google-cloud-firestore](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/index.html) for Python as follows:

```py
user_doc = users_coll.add(user)
```

The problem is that this way the `msgId1` is added as a string rather than a reference.

Any idea how I can set the field-type to reference programmatically in my Python script?

Comment: Can you update your code to show where is `msgId1` coming from? It must be declared somewhere?

Comment: @ChristopherPeisert thanks for the link. It was exactly what I was searching for :)

Comment: @arashjavanmard Would you mind to post solution as a formal answer to help other users that have a similar problem?